# Cost minimizing algorithm (time limited)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mathematical-optimization

Let's say I have a group of **N** people who is going to travel by train. I need to organize them in a line to the ticket office in a way that minimizes the total tickets cost. The cost can be minimized if families buy family tickets and people travelling to the same destination buy group tickets.

I do not know who of these people are families and where are they travelling.

All I can do is to send any **M (1 <= M <= N)** of them to the ticket office and get the answer, how much it will cost for these **M** people.

I also have a **limited time**, as a train is leaving in some minutes, so the near best solution is good enough for me.

The brute force solution is O(N!) and so is obviously unacceptable.

**EDIT**

The answer from the ticket office is always the total sum for M people, no details.

Group and/or family may start at 2 people and may include all N of them.

The cushier in the tickets office will always know who is a family and who is not.

**EDIT**

If I am sending to the tickets office a family and some more people, the family will not get a family ticket, they all will get their regular tickets.

Comment: How long do you have, and how good a solution do you need? What relative weight should we give to minimizing cost and minimizing attempts?

Comment: What are the constraints on buying family or group tickets? Can we assume families are traveling to the same destination? Is there a minimum family or group size to buy family or group tickets? Give us a complete problem specification.

Comment: What answer will you get if you send three people to the ticket office where two are headed towards the same destination and one is not?

Comment: Minimizing costs ia s top priority, but I will need to stop my algorithm when the time is over.

Comment: Regarding your edit. Isn't the problem trivial under these conditions? Send all people together to the ticket office and let the cashier figure out who is a family or a group?

Comment: No, see my second edit

Comment: it's unacceptable for O(n!), but is it okay if it is O(2^n)?

Comment: The question is not about what is acceptable or not, it is about the best time possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned you can settle for 'good enough', and you are time limited - here is a greedy [any-time approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anytime_algorithm):

1. p <- Create a random permutation
2. estimate the cost of this permutation. (let that be `cost`)
3. Find a new permutation `p'` such that `cost(p') < cost(p)` that is achieved from `p` using a single swap of two people (there are n(n-1)/2 such possible swaps)<sup>1</sup>
4. If such p' exist: `p <- p'` and return to 2.
5. Else, store `p` as a local minimum, and return to 1.
6. When time is up - choose the best local minimum found.

This is basically a variation of [steepest ascent hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) with random restarts.

Note that if your `time->infinity`, you will find optimal solution,
   because the probability of checking any possible permutation is
   getting closer and closer to 1 as time passes.

---

(1) getting the price can be done by first checking who is a family member/going to the same destination and is adjacent to each other in the permutation at `O(n)`using the fact that `d(passenger1,passenger2) < d(passenger1) + d(passenger2)`, and then checking each group separately.

Comment: Thanks, I am giving it a try.

Comment: @Flot2011 Also look at the edit (footnote 1) - I forgot to mention it at first, but it might be important to solving your problem.

Comment: I finished using the simulated annealing algorithm, but thanks for pointing me the right direction. Answer accepted.